# Removing a block of lines from a txt file

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-2.7

I have a .txt file which has a structure like this:

```
name
parameter 1
parameter 2
parameter 3
\n
name2
p1
p2
p3
\n
(...)
```

I don't know how to make a function that remove a block (name, parameters and \n) from a file, which get name as an function argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rmblock(path, block):                           
    lines = open(path).readlines()                  
    blockstart = lines.index(block + "\n")          
    blockend = lines.index(r"\n" + "\n", blockstart)
    del(lines[blockstart:blockend+1])               
    open(path, 'w+').writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, but didn't exacly worked. But blockend didn't have to be used, cause each block has same number of parameters so i used:
del(lines[blockstart:blockstart+5])

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as deleting from a file. You can only read and write to a file. But you can delete items from a list in Python, or omit them in iteration:

```
In [1]: def exclude(f, name):
   ...:     with open(f) as fo:
   ...:         found = False
   ...:         for line in fo:
   ...:             if line.strip() == name:
   ...:                 found = True
   ...:                 continue
   ...:             if found and not line.strip():
   ...:                 found = False
   ...:             if not found:
   ...:                 yield line
   ...: 

In [2]: with open('/tmp/new.txt', 'w') as new:
   ...:     new.writelines(exclude('/tmp/text.txt', 'name'))
   ...:
```

This example writes a new file without the block starting with `"name"`. It assumes that the blocks are separated with blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use readline:
[readline() from tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm) or
[this one is from python documentation about readline](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

1. read every line from source file.
2. if the line consist function parameters (name or anything), then continue, (don't read this line, jump to next line).
3. then append every filtered line to create new file.